Update Azure cosmos NoSQL container record without updating _ts
we are using Azure cosmos DB NOSQL that has a container say a. We are using .Net core 7 and using CosmosClient for CRUD operations. We need to update the document in container a but without changing _ts because we use _ts to track concurrency from UI.
We checked Partial document Update
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partial-document-update-getting-started?tabs=dotnet  but _ts will be changed or not is not clear? So not sure should we use Partial document Update or not?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partial-document-update-faq#is-partial-document-update-supported-for-system-generated-properties-


The internal-use properties such as _ts are not under your control. _ts will be updated with any document update, just like _etag. If you require your own timestamp for your UI, you'll need to add an additional property to track timestamp, in whatever way you want to store it: ticks, seconds, etc.
